# Comma and Dot concurrently on rails in numeric fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

somebody know a trick for use Comma and Dot concurrently in a decimal field, because the international separator is the Dot but in some country is the Comma.
i've try with a Before_validation, but i've a lot of problem, sometimes works sometimes doesn't, this is the code:

```
def update_fields
    [:field_1, :field_2, :field_3].each { |k|
      unless k != nil
        self[k.to_sym] = self.attributes_before_type_cast[k.to_s].gsub(/[.,]/, '.' => '', ',' => '.')
      end
    }
end
```

thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try it: 
add it to you GemFile

```
gem 'i18n_alchemy'
```

And after :

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include I18n::Alchemy
  localize [:field1, field2, field3], using: :number
end
```

Comment: this response does not provide indications as to how to use it in the controller, for example...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you accept *thousand separator* in your front end, simply change everything to *dots*:

```
value.tr!(',', '.')
```

With thousand separators the task becomes much more convoluted, and the easiest way to handle it is to standardize everything on *client side*, aka front end, with javascript, since there in browser the user’s locale settings are available.